# in order to parse html to string I used tika parser but i faced some problems such as libraries and errors in jdeveloper

Tags: java, html, apache, apache-tika

Firstly, I have to download tika-bundle-0.9.jar but I cannot find it. 
Seconly,I wrote these

```
 try {
        URL itemURL = new URL("");
        DataInputStream daHTMLfromDaItem = new DataInputStream(itemURL.openStream());
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Reader reader = tika.parse(daHTMLfromDaItem, metadata);

          String s=reader.toString();
          //System.out.print(s);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

errors

```
Error(5,24): cannot access class org.apache.tika.Tika; class file has wrong version 49.0, should be 45.3 or 46.0 or 47.0 or 48.0

Error(6,33): cannot access class org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata; class file has wrong version 49.0, should be 45.3 or 46.0 or 47.0 or 48.0

Error(15,13): class Tika not found in class mypackage.TikaParsing

Error(15,29): class Tika not found in class mypackage.TikaParsing

Error(16,13): class Metadata not found in class mypackage.TikaParsing

Error(16,37): class Metadata not found in class mypackage.TikaParsing
```

Also, I have to say that I added all necessary libraries except tika-bundle-0.9.jar . Do some problems occur because of tika-bundle-0.9.jar and how can i find tika-bundle-0.9.jar? I cannot find solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tika libraries have been compiled with Java 1.5 but you try to run them within a Java 1.4 environment. That's what the first error message is telling us. Version `49.0` is generated by Java 1.5, Version `48.0` by Java 1.4.x

Either run your application with Java 1.5+ or try to find an old version of tika that is compatible with Java 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

The Tika Bundle is available from Maven. If you're using maven, then add something like:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
   <artifactId>tika-bundle</artifactId>
   <version>0.9</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

If you're not using maven, then grab it by hand from a nearby maven repo, eg http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-bundle/ (each version is in its own subdirectory)